# Prove $S^2$ is closed via limit/accumulation points

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

let $S^2 = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1^{\:2} +  x_2^{\:2} +  x_3^{\:2} = 1\}$ and let $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^3}$be the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^3$

The euclidean balls of $\mathbb{R}^3$ form a basis for $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^3}$. If a euclidean ball of $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at an element $x$ of $S^2$ contains an element of $S^2$ other than $x$, then this must hold true for the open subsets $U_x \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^3}$

If $x \in S^2$ and $B_r(x)$ is an open euclidean ball of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, it can be proven that $B_r(x) \cap S^2 = \{y \in S^2: acos(x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3) < r\}$  or $B_r(x) \cap S^2 = S^2$

for any $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ for the first case, we can always find valid values for $r$ between $0$ and $r$, which implies the ball contains elements of $S^2$ other than $x$. For the second case, all of $S^2$ trivially contains elements of $S^2$ other than $x$. Therefore, all of the sphere's points are limit points. However, it still needs to be proven that they are all of the sphere's limit points.

Using contradiction to prove all of the sphere's points are all of the sphere's limit points, suppose $S^2$ doesn't contain all its limit points

$\Rightarrow$ there is at least one limit point of $S^2$ that's not in $S^2$

$\Rightarrow \exists x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x \notin S^2 \:\:\text{and}\:\: \forall U_x \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^3}, U_x \setminus \{x\} \cap S^2 \neq \emptyset$

this can't be true because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff, meaning that...

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x \notin S^2, \exists U_x \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}^3}: U_x \cap S^2 = \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow$ there are no limit points of $S^2$ that aren't in $S^2$

$\Rightarrow S^2$ contains all its limit points

Comment: You don't need to wrap everything you write in `$$`.. You can just encase your $\rm\LaTeX$ in `$$`.

Comment: Shouldn’t you use the actual definition of the sphere somewhere?

Comment: If you were allowed other methods,  the simplest method is to show it's the inverse image of a closed set from a continuous function.  That's a 1 line proof :)